# React Router V4 switch vs div?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I have seen various examples saying that when using React Router V4, you can wrap your `<Route />` components in either a `<Switch>` component provided by React Router, or you can use any other element to contain your routes (such as a `<div>`).

What is the difference between these two approaches?

Examples:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <div>
    <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginScreen} />
    <Route path="/loading" component={LoadingScreen} />
  </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

VS

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginScreen} />
    <Route path="/loading" component={LoadingScreen} />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`<Switch/>`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch) components will only show the first matched child [`<Route/>`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route) for any given [`path`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/path-string). Other configs will show all matches.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, exact will also do the same thing

Comment: Unfortunately not. Multiple routes can have matching `path` props and be concurrently returned under most configs, despite also having `exact={true}` @bajran